# Import and Export DateObject

Tags: export, import, date-and-time, spreadsheets

I'm trying to import a spreadsheet with dates and export it again. But the cell reads ### in the exported file. It's shown in the screenshots. This is my code.

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
file = Import["import.xlsx"];
Export["export.xlsx", file];
```

Is there some way to get this working? I'd like the export file being the same as the import file.

I was trying this with Mathematica 12 on Linux and Mathematica 11 on Windows.

Here's the import file.

http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=34471371704061438491

Thanks a lot!

[image]
[image]

Comment: probably has to do with the dateformat that is set up in Excel/Libreoffice. As you can see in the cell content, the date is correctly exported from Wolfram.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the file is a list of dates and that the issue isn't a formatting of the cell in Libreoffice then you could do this:

```
file = Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "importdate.xlsx"]; 
fileII = DateString[#, "ISODate"] & /@ Flatten[file]; 
Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "export.xlsx", fileII]
```

[DateString](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateString.html) will format the date as an ISO date

Comment: Thanks, that works! I still wonder if it's possible to export the DateObject as such in the excel format but that's more curiosity. (By the way, I tried with both, LibreOffice and MS Office - it's the same)

Comment: Note that ISODate was introduced in Mathematica version 12.